# SELECTing percentage and count of votes

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following tables structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `options` (
  `option_id` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `poll_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `option` tinytext NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `option_id_poll_id` (`option_id`,`poll_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Storing poll options/choices';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `poll_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `question` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`poll_id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table to store poll questions/titles';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `poll_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `option_id` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `poll_id_nick` (`poll_id`,`nick`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am displaying details for a particular `poll_id` using the following query:

```
SELECT
    o.option_id AS option_id,
    o.`option` AS `option`,
    COUNT(v.nick) AS total,
    FLOOR(
        ( COUNT(v.nick) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM votes WHERE poll_id = %d) ) * 100
    ) AS percentage
FROM options o
LEFT JOIN votes v
    ON o.poll_id = v.poll_id
    AND v.option_id = o.option_id
WHERE o.poll_id = %d
GROUP BY o.option_id
ORDER BY total DESC, o.option_id ASC;
```

I am not satisfied with the way that I am calculating the percentage votes on each of the available options! `%d` is place-holder for `string.format` function.

I'd like a review on the query/table structures above.

Comment: In Oracle, you could use an Analytic Function to calculate this without a subquery, but MySQL doesn't have an equivalent.  Your solution may be best.

Comment: @Scott: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806528/does-mysql-have-the-equivalent-of-oracles-analytic-functions, something similar to Oracle Analytic Function: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to realize that you must be considering a poll to be a single question (posted on a web page) that allows people to pick from a series of options for that single question.

Some things to consider:

- [options] Consider reversing the index field order. It would seem probable that you will want to query up the options for a poll without specifying the option_id.
- [questions] There appears to be no real point to indexing the deleted bit. When pulling questions up for a poll you can certainly exclude those that are deleted without needing an index.
- [votes] I'm guessing that 'nick' is the login name of the user choosing an option from a single question poll?
- Look at an [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see if MySQL has optimized your sub-query into a single lookup. If not, do your own explicit query or consider using [group by modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to do a rollup when you pull up poll stats. Then, in either case, as you load records for a poll (as you'll have some code for web display purposes) do the percentage calculation as you generate the output table.

Finally, it is customary to "select count(*) from tab" when you don't care about the columns involved.